# Videos are not playing in browser after publishing results by Robot Framework Jenkins in Chrome

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, screen-capture

I have a script that does web actions in a web application after opening a chrome browser. I used [ScreenCap](https://mihaiparvu.github.io/ScreenCapLibrary/ScreenCapLibrary.html) library to record the script execution. When opening the logs in the machine where the script has executed then able to view the video in log and it's getting played. However, when opening the logs in Jenkins after the execution and publishing results using [RobotFramework plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot/) video is not playing.

Blank space is displaying in log.html after opening it in the browsers(Chrome & Firefox).

Video template with duration zero is displaying while clicking the empty space in the log.html in the Chrome browser and the video is getting played when I click the blank space in the Firefox browser

If I download the results as a zip from Jenkins and open the log.html from the downloads then able to view the video and it is playing.

Any idea what might be the reason. Thank you..!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the file reference to the video isn't a local file? If so, then this would explain why it works locally, but not in a server environment.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I just checked and the path of video file is from the /robot folder in Jenkins and it is not from local.

Comment: The interesting thing to add on here is, when I open the log file in the firefox browser and click the empty space where the video is located then the video is getting played

Comment: This is very difficult to reproduce.  Have you done [as much research as possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)?